Result throw Namespace prefix 'ext' is not defined
I tried to add XmlDsigXPathTransform to reference but the code signedXml.ComputeSignature() throws an error

Namespace prefix 'ext' is not defined

This is the code:
//Generate the xmlDoc
AXG_Invoice.Invoice obj = new AXG_Invoice.Invoice();
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

<...code to generate the xml content here...>

CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(CustomXmlDsigC14NTransform), "https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n11/#");
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2('p12', 'password', X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var exportedKeyMaterial = cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString( /* includePrivateParameters = */ true);
var key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(new CspParameters(24 /* PROV_RSA_AES */));
key.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
key.FromXmlString(exportedKeyMaterial);

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AXG_Invoice.Invoice));
var myNameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

myNameSpace.Add("cac", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2");
myNameSpace.Add("cbc", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2");
myNameSpace.Add("ext", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2");
myNameSpace.Add("sig", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2");
myNameSpace.Add("sac", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2");
myNameSpace.Add("sbc", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2");
myNameSpace.Add("ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");

string serializedXml;
using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, obj, myNameSpace);
    serializedXml = textWriter.ToString();
}

xmlDoc.LoadXml(serializedXml);
xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;

XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsManager.AddNamespace("ext", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2");
nsManager.AddNamespace("cac", "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2");

XAdESSignedXml signedXml = new XAdESSignedXml(xmlDoc);
signedXml.Signature.Id = "signature";
signedXml.SigningKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = "https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n11/#";
signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
Reference reference = new Reference("");
reference.Uri = "";
reference.Id = "id-doc-signed-data";
reference.AddTransform(new CustomXmlDsigC14NTransform());
reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
      
<...Code to generate XAdES here...>
DataObject dataObject = new DataObject
{
  Data = qualifyingPropertiesRoot.SelectNodes("."),
};

signedXml.AddObject(dataObject);

// Create a reference to the XML document
Reference reference = new Reference("");
reference.Uri = "";
reference.Id = "id-doc-signed-data";
reference.AddTransform(new CustomXmlDsigC14NTransform());
reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";

reference.AddTransform(CreateXPathTransform("not(//ancestor-or-self::ext:UBLExtensions)"));
reference.AddTransform(CreateXPathTransform("not(//ancestor-or-self::cac:Signature)"));

// Add the reference to the SignedXml object
signedXml.AddReference(reference);

Reference referenceXades = new Reference();
referenceXades.Uri = "#id-xades-signed-props";
referenceXades.Type = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties";
referenceXades.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
signedXml.AddReference(referenceXades);

// Add an RSAKeyValue KeyInfo (optional; helps recipient find key to validate).
KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));
signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

// Compute the signature
signedXml.ComputeSignature();

public class CustomXmlDsigC14NTransform : XmlDsigC14NTransform
{
  public CustomXmlDsigC14NTransform() : base(false)
  {
    this.Algorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11";
  }
}

private static XmlDsigXPathTransform CreateXPathTransform(string xpath)
{
      XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
      XmlElement xpathElem = doc.CreateElement("XPath");
      xpathElem.InnerText = xpath;

      XmlDsigXPathTransform xform = new XmlDsigXPathTransform();
      xform.LoadInnerXml(xpathElem.SelectNodes("."));
      
      return xform;
}

Update:
Here attached the full XML that successfully generate if use //ancestor-or-self
//just to prove the code is able to generate the xml.
<Invoice
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
    xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2"
    xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
    xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2"
    xmlns:sbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2"
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <ext:ExtensionURI>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</ext:ExtensionURI>
            <ext:ExtensionContent>
                <sig:UBLDocumentSignatures>
                    <sac:SignatureInformation>
                        <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:1</cbc:ID>
                        <sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</sbc:ReferencedSignatureID>
                        <Signature Id="signature"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                            <SignedInfo>
                                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
                                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                                <Reference Id="id-doc-signed-data" URI="">
                                    <Transforms>
                                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
                                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                            <XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self)</XPath>
                                        </Transform>
                                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                            <XPath>not(//ancestor-or-self)</XPath>
                                        </Transform>
                                    </Transforms>
                                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                    <DigestValue>hSjFxSXw+GNu3YUqVIKSfjweSZOlqEHJFb3Wo0kvFTk=</DigestValue>
                                </Reference>
                                <Reference URI="#id-xades-signed-props" Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties">
                                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                    <DigestValue>5twLsAWM/n8Y2F2nHWZOFRYL+gzi9/pSKGNG4629H4A=</DigestValue>
                                </Reference>
                            </SignedInfo>
                            <SignatureValue>Sf1GpkVrJHACFkx4IKAbAyCpsBtf5VmHW8KxBP+MQRMPHEnvyysEC4A4+eaVXsEX+Yo7oPMh8R92WTfYgWY1qVPQ7HzpjKboWEHS0HjBobFcMYoEFo6WVYQoaBNQfK0YRAQJ4cvijK+5zKmyA2VVPgX4xXNHMjNjyj1ScspAvvqL/mP/EFtI/uqQdfW5c72CeBrybD1en+OwubdR70e+8iEBfwMTQtr7hW1ectcOLW44IOoXdoDbTNF9V+utx6oEi8/N0B+MwSZPvslym/EWFwNd5IyU9cuOnPL5fGiO17BGRdHvqoCCyyVpdFVLcomBbNm/x86FdeZuFspsilzubw==</SignatureValue>
                            <KeyInfo>
                                <X509Data>
                                    <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
                                </X509Data>
                            </KeyInfo>
                            <Object>
                                <xades:QualifyingProperties Target="signature"
                                    xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#">
                                    <xades:SignedProperties Id="id-xades-signed-props">
                                        <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                            <xades:SigningTime>2024-06-12T16:39:07.361Z</xades:SigningTime>
                                            <xades:SigningCertificate>
                                                <xades:Cert>
                                                    <xades:CertDigest>
                                                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                                        <ds:DigestValue>7dEZe2D1zsX9WEcLAsYM1grdBlq6Iq+moSK1NqJipVo=</ds:DigestValue>
                                                    </xades:CertDigest>
                                                    <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                        <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=LHDNM Sub CA G3, OU=Terms of use at http://www.posdigicert.com.my, O=LHDNM, C=MY</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                                        <ds:X509SerialNumber>011C3026</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                                                    </xades:IssuerSerial>
                                                </xades:Cert>
                                            </xades:SigningCertificate>
                                        </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                                    </xades:SignedProperties>
                                </xades:QualifyingProperties>
                            </Object>
                        </Signature>
                    </sac:SignatureInformation>
                </sig:UBLDocumentSignatures>
            </ext:ExtensionContent>
        </ext:UBLExtension>
    </ext:UBLExtensions>
    <cbc:ID>FIN-000017</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2024-06-12</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:IssueTime>16:39:06Z</cbc:IssueTime>
    <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode listVersionID="1.0">01</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
    <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>MYR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
    <cac:Signature>
        <cbc:ID>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:signature:Invoice</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:SignatureMethod>urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:dsig:enveloped:xades</cbc:SignatureMethod>
    </cac:Signature>
    <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cbc:IndustryClassificationCode name="Activities of providing infrastructure for hosting, data processing services and related activities">63111</cbc:IndustryClassificationCode>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cbc:ID>C23849751080</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cbc:RegistrationName>Suntax Malaysia Sdn Bhd</cbc:RegistrationName>
            </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
            <cac:Contact>
                <cbc:Telephone>Activities of providing infrastructure for hosting, data processing services and related activities</cbc:Telephone>
                <cbc:ElectronicMail>0123456845</cbc:ElectronicMail>
            </cac:Contact>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>0.00</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>156.00</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
    </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
</Invoice>


So what have I done wrong?

Don't give us code fragments, especially ones which apparently are executing in a different order to that in which you present them. Give us a [mcve] that we can actually run and don't have to reconstruct based on your narrative.

I am very sorry because when 1st time posting it not allow me to post the full code due some validation, i already updated the codes.
